# How to convert a line of code from Objective-C to Swift in sorting array?

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, swift, sorting

I have been trying to convert lines of code from **Objective-C** to **Swift** in sorting *array*. The codes I'm converting is our existing application in Objective-C that needs to convert to Swift. How do I translate the codes below to Swift?

**This is the code I need to translate to Swift**

```
[marrBackupList sortUsingFunction:sortItem context: nil];
[txtList sortUsingFunction:sortString context: nil];
```

**This is what I had when I converted it to Swift**

```
  marrBackupList = marrBackupList?.sortedArray(sortItem, context: nil) as? [AnyHashable] ?? marrBackupList
  txtList = (txtList as NSArray).sortedArray(sortString, context: nil) as? [AnyHashable] ?? txtList
```

[kindly check this link for the screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF0hH.png)

*I converted this line already with the help of a good samaritan here in stackoverflow that might help support the code that needs to translate*

```
 //------------------------------
 //OBJ C TO SWIFT
 //------------------------------
 NSComparisonResult sortItem (id data1, id data2, void* context)
 {
  NSMetadataItem *item1 = data1;
  NSMetadataItem *item2 = data2;

 NSString* string1 = [[item1 valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey]lastPathComponent];
NSString* string2 = [[item2 valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey]lastPathComponent];

return [string1 compare:string2];
}
```

**CONVERTED TO SWIFT**

```
 func sortItem(_ data1: Any?, _ data2: Any?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {
    let item1 = data1 as? NSMetadataItem
    let item2 = data2 as? NSMetadataItem

    guard let string1 = item1?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedAscending
    }

    guard let string2 = item2?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? String else {
        return .orderedDescending
    }

    return string1.compare(string2)
}
```

**Also converted from Obj-C to Swift**

```
  //---------------------------------
  //OBJ C TO SWIFT
  //----------------------------------
NSComparisonResult sortString (id data1, id data2, void* context)
{
NSString* string1 = data1;
NSString* string2 = data2;

return [string1 compare:string2];
}
```

**CONVERTED TO SWIFT**

```
 func sortString(_ data1: Any?, _ data2: Any?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> ComparisonResult {
    let string1 = data1 as? String
    let string2 = data2 as? String

    return (string1!.compare(string2 ?? ""))
}
```

`sortItem` and `sortString` is already converted. I included here for reference for the flow of the codes.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what part of the code is giving you an issue?

Comment: Hi, i got error in this part `[marrBackupList sortUsingFunction:sortItem context: nil];
[txtList sortUsingFunction:sortString context: nil];`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried to convert that code into this but I just encountered error. `marrBackupList = marrBackupList?.sortedArray(sortItem, context: nil) as? [AnyHashable] ?? marrBackupList
          txtList = (txtList as NSArray).sortedArray(sortString, context: nil) as? [AnyHashable] ?? txtList`

Comment: Add this information to your question instead and remove anything that isn’t relevant to the question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I edited my post and add information, hope it can help to understand my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The attempt to translate ObjC code literally to Swift is always a bad idea.**

First of all declare `marrBackupList` as native Swift array

```
var marrBackupList = [NSMetadataItem]()
```

Basically avoid to use `NSArray/NSDictionary` in Swift as much as possible. Foundation collection types lack type information.

---

The Swift `sort(by:` function is very similar to the ObjC *comparator* but it's static typed by default.

This is the equivalent of `sortItem`, unlike `id` (aka `Any`) in ObjC `rhs` and `lhs` are static `NSMetadataItemURLKey`. The *extended* syntax is necessary to handle the optionals.

```
marrBackupList.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    guard let lURL = lhs.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? URL,
        let rURL = rhs.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? URL else { return false }
    return lURL.lastPathComponent < rURL.lastPathComponent
}
```

`sort{ ... }` is the trailing closure syntax of `sort(by: { ... })`

---

To sort a non-optional string array

```
var txtList = [String]()
```

is much simpler, just specify the operator `<` for ascending or `>` for descending.

This is the equivalent of `sortString`, pretty clean, isn't it?

```
txtList.sort(by: <)
```

`sort(by: <)` is a shorter syntax of `sort(by: {$0 < $1})` which is a shorter syntax of `sort(by: {lhs, rhs -> Bool in return lhs < rhs })`

Comment: thank you for your help and giving me some techniques. :)